# React-Native Firebase Deploy Error command Cli

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, deployment

Hi everyone i try to pass some images to my firebase with Functions but when i deploy firebase(with cli firebase deploy)inside my terminal i got an error and the deploy abort.
Apparently the error say my require inside function/index.js is not a function (line 9 col 45) but the gcconfig was do with the right method for me.
I want to correctly deploy firebase from CLI.

The error from cli firebase deploy i got on my terminal:

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

TypeError: require(...) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/luca/Code/Code_Taff/Benibla/bnblproto/functions/index.js:9:45)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:544:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:536:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:15:15
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:53:3)
```

function/index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const fs = require('fs');
const UUID = require("uuid-v4");

const gcconfig = {
  projectId: "beniblaproto",
  keyFilename: "beniblaproto.json"
};

const gcs = require("@google-cloud/storage")(gcconfig);

exports.storeImage = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  return cors(request, response, () => {
    const body = JSON.parse(request.body);
    fs.writeFileSync("/tmp/uploaded-image.jpg", body.image, "base64", err => {
      console.log(err);
      return response.status(500).json({error: err});
      });
      const bucket = gcs.bucket("beniblaproto.appspot.com");
      const uuid = UUID();

      return bucket.upload(
        "/tmp/uploaded-image.jpg",
        {
          uploadType: "media",
          destination: "/events/" + uuid + ".jpg",
          metadata: {
            metadata: {
              contentType: "image.jpg",
              firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid
            }
          }
        },
        (err, file) => {
        if (!err) {
          response.status(201).json({
            imageUrl: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.con/v0/b" +
              bucket.name + 
              "/o/" + 
              encodeURIComponent(file.name) + 
              "?alt=media&token=" + 
              uuid
          });
        } else {
          console.log(err);
          response.status(500).json({error: err});
        }
      }
    );
  });
});
```

if someone can explain me where and for what i fail.
Thank you all have a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to import {Storage} of library;

```
const {Storage} = require("@google-cloud/storage");
```

after that you need to take an instance with your configuration object;

```
const gcs = new Storage(gcconfig);
```